# one-time only poll email link

Tags: 6, rules, emails

How can i send only one time use email link to  for polling and if the user click that link again than he will be redirected to the revise the poll page.Is there any way to do this using contrib module if no any suggestion which is the best approach do it by custom code .I am using **Drupal6**

Comment: Not sure about poll in D6. But in D7 when you link to a poll node page you can vote. When you visit that link again you can revise your options.

Comment: I am not using polling module exactly it is kinda different , i am just sending email to some email account and asking them to answer the question and even annonymous user can answer the question using that link but only once and later when they click on the link they can revise their answer.

Comment: Take a look at the poll module, I think it might work for your needs